# write radare2 output to a file

Tags: disassembly, debugging, radare2

I am trying to write all the write logs of a binary program into a file for further analysis. I am using radare2 for it. I don't know what's the issue, I am not able to write the 'dte' output to a file. It prints on the console but doesn't write to a file even after redirection. 'dtd' is working fine and writing to the file. Here in the below code log2.txt comes up empty.

```
import r2pipe

r = r2pipe.open('simpleAES', flags=['-d'])
r.cmd('aei')
r.cmd('dc')
r.cmd('e dbg.trace=1')
r.cmd('des 100') 

output1 = r.cmd('dtd')
output2 = r.cmd('dte')

f = open("log1.txt", "w")
f.write(output1)
f.close()

f = open("log2.txt", "w")
f.write(output2)
f.close()
```

I am using a simple C code for analysis and using raise(SIGINT); for setting breakpoint in the C program. Do you have any idea how I can write the 'dte' output to a file.

Code that I am debugging:

```
#include <signal.h>
#include<stdio.h>
int main (void)
{
    printf("loop started");
    raise(SIGINT);
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
      printf("Hello ");
    }
    printf("loop completed");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you clarify how you set breakpoints?

Comment: using `raise(SIGINT)` in the C program to set the breakpoint.

Comment: Can you show this program?

Comment: @bart1e added the code.

Comment: `raise(SIGINT)` will send to your program `SIGINT` signal (it's like pressing `CTRL+C` - it will terminate your application if no handler for `SIGINT` is registered). If you want to set breakpoint in C, you can use `asm("int $3")` in GCC, or `db address` in r2.